# How do I fetch last 3 digits of a string in c#

Tags: c#

How could I get the *last three digits* of this `string`?

```cs
var myString = "77441-Megrhfj654JHK";
```

Comment: Does the position of the last digits vary?

Comment: in case of `"77441-Megrhfj54JHK"` the last 3 digits would be `"154"` right?

Comment: If it has to be consecutive digits, would `123_4567` return `123` as the last group of 3?

Comment: @Twenty No,654 always constant.

Comment: @fubo "654"  always Constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions* to get last exactly `3` digits in a row:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  var myString = "77441-Megrhfj654JHK";

  // Exactly 3 digits while start matching from the right
  string digits = Regex.Match(myString, "[0-9]{3}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value;

  Console.WriteLine(digits);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  654
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for `"1_2_3_goal:456_7_8_9"` where the answer is `789`.

Comment: @Scroog1: it depends on what exactly we are looking for. I suggest that it is "the last exactly `3` digits in a row" (so the answer is `"456"` in my interpretation); it well may be that your reading is correct: "combine the last 3 digits (not necessary in a row)"

Answer (score 4):

Very straight forward LINQ example

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string GetLastDigits( this string source, int count )
    {
        return new string( source
            .Where(ch => Char.IsDigit(ch))
            .Reverse()
            .Take(count)
            .Reverse()
            .ToArray());
    }
}
```

See working example on [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TNbYzW)

Comment: Possible counter example: `"1_2_3_goal:456_7_8_9"`: we want `"456"` but actual is `"789"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko although you are correct with your comment, the OP is not asking for the last 3 consecutive digits, but asking for the last 3 digits, which would in fact in your example be 789.

Answer (score 3):

In C# 8, you can use a [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range?view=netcore-3.0): `myString[^3..];`

Assuming that the input string is in a fixed format:

```cs
var lastThree = myString[^6..^3];
```

Or, in older C# versions:

```cs
var lastThree = myString.Substring(13, 3);
```

For just the last three numeric digits anywhere, something like:

```cs
var digits = new string(myString.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
var lastThree = digits[^3..];
```

Comment: That aren't the last 3 **digits**, but the last 3 **characters**?

Comment: Possible counter example: `"1_2_3_goal:456_7_8_9"`: we want `"456"` but actual is `"789"`

Comment: `789` looks like the expected answer to me. They just asked for the last 3 digits, not the last 3 consecutive digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "77441-Megrhfj654JHK";
var digits = Regex.Match(myString, "[0-9]").Value;
return digits.Substring(Math.Max(digits.Length - 3,0));
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32()` drops leading zero digits - i would keep it type `string`

Comment: And in case of less than 3 digits in your string, you will get a `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: @fubo yes thats right, this only work if we assum that the string will contain always 3 or more digits